# Rendering a graph with PhantomJS and taking a snapshot

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want to generate a chart to add to an email. I was thinking of using PhantomJS to do this. I am using version 2.0 of PhantomJS. I want to load d3.js (on cloudfare) and c3.js (which is in a local js file). I am missing something here. When I run the script with PhantomJS it returns d3 as undefined on the window object.

My code below does not work:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
page.viewportSize = { width: 400, height : 400 };
page.content = '<html><body><canvas id="surface"></canvas> <button>Hello world</button> </body></html>';
page.includeJs("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js");
var c3_js = "./c3.min.js";
page.includeJs(c3_js);

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
  var c3 = page.evaluate(function() {
          return window;
  });

  console.log(c3.d3);

  page.render('test.png');
  phantom.exit();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with your code:

- [`page.includeJs(url, callback)`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html) is an asynchronous function, so you need to put the code that needs the JavaScript that it includes into the callback (which you don't have at all).
- You need to use [`page.injectJs(filename)`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html) for local files (c3.js).
- You cannot return `window` from the page context, because it is not a primitive object that can be serialized. From the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

  > **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
  >
  > **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

  Either you do everything in the page context (inside of `page.evaluate()`) or you can return some *representation* of the stuff to the outside. If you decide to do it in the page context, then you should look into the various event listeners such as `page.onConsoleMessage` to see console messages from the page context and `page.onCallback`.